# How to call methods of another Activity

Tags: android

I am using 3 classes A, B and C. In class A I created a method clickButton() and In class B I used onClick() for a button. while clicking on the button it has to call the method clickButton() in Class A, and inside the clickButton() i wrote intent for initiating the class C.

The problem is I couldn't able to call the Class A method in class B.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? Are you getting any type of error? Or are you just not able to get an instance of said Class A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally don't want to touch another `Activity` directly.  The Android design paradigm represents a largely separated viewpoint between different activities, and so instead of directly calling methods on a class `A`, you will send it an `Intent` or message or something.  If you have a utility method, you should consider moving them into a shared class and making them static.  If you have something that needs to be performed in the background or shared persistent store, you should consider moving to a service or content provider.

Comment: Of sending an intent to the other app?  You can google Intents and then Google for service examples.